# Comparing primitive type with generic type

Tags: java, operator-keyword

How can I compare generic member with say a primitive type?

Say,

```
void method(T k) {
   if(k < 10) ...
}
```

Unlike C/C++ one cannot overload operators in Java, right?
In order to evaluate the above snippet, do I have to cast k into the actual type? Is there a more elegant way to solve this than using casting?

Comment: T could be anything: a Car, a Plane, a Banana, a Socket. What would `socket < 10` mean?

Comment: Have you specified what `T` is? ie. have you used `<T extends Number>` when you declared it?

Comment: I would like to define what it means by overloading the operator. Say T is a car, and k would stand for PS.

Comment: @Edd T is a Integer during runtime - but could also be float, string or something else. No, I have not used T extends Number - good point, that would solve my question for all number types.

Comment: Java doesn't have operator overloading. Use <T extends SomeInterface>, and add the method `compareWithInt(int i)` to SomeInterface. Make Car and all the other classes you want to pass to this method extend SomeInterface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your generic type could be forced to implement a certain interface wich does the comparison in a seperate method. With this version your class T could also be dereived from another class.

```
public interface CompareToInt {

    public boolean less(int that);
}
```

Your class with your method:

```
public class Dummy<T extends CompareToInt> {

    void method(T k){
        if (k.less(10)){
            // ... do stuff
        }
    }
}
```

**edit:**

my solution was inspired by popalka's

Answer (score 4):

If your type T extends Number, use this information in class signature

```
public class Num<T extends Number> {

    void method(T a){
        if (a.intValue()<10){

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: this is a nice solution! another one could be: use an interface with a specific method for this comparison, so you don't have problems when your class has to be derived from a different baseclass than number